Twitter V2 api 401 unauthorized when posting reply, twitter-v2 js
I am creating a simple twitter bot that searches for relevant hashtags and replies to them. I am using bearer token to search for the tweets and consumer keys to post reply.
User auth settings are set to Read and Write and all my keys are correct. However I am getting 401 unauthorized when sending the reply. I am paying $100 per month for the basic plan.


// Create object reference to libs
const Twitter = require('twitter-v2');
var fs = require('fs');

// Set Twitter API keys
var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = '..';
var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = '..';
var TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = '..';
var TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '..';

var BEARER_TOKEN = '..';

// Database file
var DB_FILE = "bot_db.txt";

// Set interval time. Try to use a not so small interval to avoid Twitter to lock your account.
var INTERVAL = 3*60*60*1000; // 3 hours

// Set Twitter search phrase. You can use hash tags or simples text. Hash tags works better. Separate with OR or AND.
var TWITTER_SEARCH_PHRASE = '#Test1 OR #Otherhashtag';

// Set max number of tweets to get on the search results each time
var TWITTER_SEARCH_MAX_RESULTS = 20;

// Set tweets to reply
var TWEETS_TO_REPLY = [
    "tweet text 1",
    "tweet text 22",
    
];

var Bot = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret: TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET 
    // bearer_token: BEARER_TOKEN
});

var Bot2 = new Twitter({
    bearer_token: BEARER_TOKEN
})


async function BotStart() {
        var myUserID = ..;
    

    console.log("> Twitter bot is running (" + Date() + ")...")

    const { data } = await Bot2.get('tweets/search/recent', {
        query: TWITTER_SEARCH_PHRASE,
        max_results: TWITTER_SEARCH_MAX_RESULTS
    });

    console.log(data);


            // DB file
            var bot_db = [];

            // If db file doesn't exist, create empty file
            if (!fs.existsSync(DB_FILE)) {
                fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(DB_FILE, 'w'));
            }

            var fileData = await fs.readFileSync(DB_FILE, 'utf8');

                    fileData = fileData.trim();
                    if (fileData != "") {
                        bot_db = fileData.split("\n");
                    }

                    var processed_tweets = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        // Tweet id
                        var id = data[i].id;

                        // If id doesn't exist on database, process it
                        if (bot_db.indexOf(id) == -1) {

                            processed_tweets.push(id);

                            fs.appendFile(DB_FILE, id + "\n", function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log("Error on save to '" + DB_FILE + "' file.");
                                }
                                else {
                                    console.log("tweet processed" + id);
                                }

                            });

                            // Reply
                            var textToReply = TWEETS_TO_REPLY[Math.floor(Math.random()*TWEETS_TO_REPLY.length)];
                            textToReply = "Hey " +  textToReply;
                            try {
                                var replyData =  await Bot.post('tweets', {text: textToReply, in_reply_to_tweet_id: id}); 

                                console.log("reply data " + textToReply);
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    // Log of processed tweets
                    if (processed_tweets.length > 0) {
                        console.log("> Tweets processed: " + processed_tweets);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("> No tweets processed.");
                    }

                }
            

        


// Start bot and timer
BotStart();
setInterval(BotStart, INTERVAL);


I tried regenerating keys many times, keep getting unauthorized.

Same happens when i try to like a tweet using: await Bot.post('users/${myUserID}/likes', {tweet_id: id});

It worked when I used the twitter-api-v2 npm package.
Maybe because I could set read write with that library using:
const rwClient1 = Bot.readWrite;

